# IP addresses not listed for IIS website bindings

Tags: windows, iis, ip, godaddy

Recently purchased a windows cloud server godaddy. Now i installed iis7 and all other required software. And i have 50.62.1.89 and 2 more public ips. Also i have a private ip 10.1.0.2. Now the problem is am unable to access any website through any public ip. All my public ips are opening default website only. also i cant see pubic ips for IIS website bindings. Only my private ip listed for IIS binding.

And in my server also public opening only default website. But am able to open websites using private ip. But my public ip addresses pointed to my server correctly. am able to open my server using remote desktop using public ip. Also as i said already public ip opening default website from IIS without problem.

Please help me. Am confused for last 2 days.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The bindings in IIS should use the internal IP. You will either have Port Forwarding Rules or Load Balancing Rules that take the external IP and translate it to the internal IP. Once translated the virtual machines will use the internal IP for everything, including bindings in IIS. When the request leaves the server the request will be translated back to the external IP.

Here is the steps to set up IIS for a working website:

1. Create or have an already working network in Go Daddy Cloud Server Console.
2. Create a windows VM
3. Under Start
4. Administrative Tools
5. Server Manager
6. Roles
7. Web Server IIS
8. Right click sites
9. Add Website
10. Site name: mysite.com
11. Physical Path: choose path to where you website will live on the filesystem. This example we will create and use: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.com
12. Binding: All Unassigned Port 80
13. Hostname mysite.com
14. Click Ok
15. Right click mysite.com
16. Edit Bindings
17. Add
18. host name: www.mysite.com
19. Click ok
20. Add your content to: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.com
21. From the Go Daddy Cloud Server console add a port forward to a public IP, please see:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/6197

At this point, if you go to yourpublicIP you will see the IIS7 welcome page. This is because this IP is owned by the Default site in IIS.

If you already have the domain pointed to your public IP, ie mysite.com resolves to yourpublicIPaddress, then visiting mysite.com will work in your web browser.

If you do not have the DNS pointed to the public IP, you can edit the hosts file on your local machine to cause the domain to resolve to that IP ON YOUR MACHINE ONLY:

For paths see:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/3354/viewing-your-website-before-changing-your-nameservers-using-host-files

Add an entry on a single line like: mysite.com 50.62.1.89

Save and close the file.

Close your web browser, reopen, and now go to mysite.com. It should work as expected.

Using the above method you can place as many websites as you want on the 50.62.1.89 IP address.

If you want a website to own everything for that IP Address.

1. Start
2. Administrative tools
3. Server Manager
4. Roles
5. Web Server IIS
6. Right click mysite.com
7. Edit Bindings
8. Add
9. IP Address: 10.1.0.2
10. Ok

Now Going to yourpublicIPaddress will show your website.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault!  Please stick around and answer all these GoDaddy questions for us!

Comment: Can't promise an answer to everything but I will do my best.

Comment: @Mike_GoDaddy What wfaulk said. =) While shilling for a product, service or vendor is met with vengeful downvoting and general teeth gnashing, vendor-supported Q/A participation is welcomed. (P.S. Greetings from a fellow Scottsdale resident)

Comment: @Mike_GoDaddy hello sir. thanks for your reply. Your post giving me some clear thought in this question. now am using Microsoft DNS Service. How i need to configure it. I need to configure Microsoft DNS with public ips or private ip?? Using this DNS my nameservers not working now. child nameservers for ns1, ns2, ns3.ghosting.in are created already. but not working. i need to do anything extra?

Comment: DNS needs to use the external IP as the Internal IP is not routable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like IIS is expecting a "Host:" header from the client that it's not getting.  Is the URL you're using a hostname or just the IP address?

Comment: its not working for both public ip and the host "classicdiagnostics.in" which pointed to that public ip. i think iis not accepting public ips. it showing only one private ip on website binding.

Answer (score 0):

The list in IIS for IP's is only pre-populated by ip addresses that the server has.
Not Public IP addresses pointed to it.

The list is just to select what IP's that the Site should answer on if you have more than one nic or ip on the server.

Check the Host Header configuration for the Default Site and see who they have configured it with the Public IP's.

My guess is that ether the server has them as a Alias on the Nic or they forward them to you.

But it should not mater. 
The only thing you have to do is configure the IIS to answer on port 80 on the hostheaders you wan't to the IP adresses that you know works to the server.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike_GoDaddy thanks for your useful reply. Now i got solution for my problem. It is my own mistake.

Before i only forward all TCP ports into the machine using Port Forward. After forwarding all ports using both TCP and UDP methods my wesite & DNS are working fine.

Thank you.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!